# List comprehension - getting error message

Tags: python, list-comprehension

I am trying to write a list comprehension which will select all numbers in a sequential list of numbers (whose length will change) which are divisible by 4.

```
end_of_quarter_dates = [i if i % 63 == 0 for i in range(0, 252)]
```

I am getting the error message "invalid syntax" for the beginning of the for loop.

Any thoughts appreciated.

Comment: As a side note, your code would test if the number is divisible by `63` and not by `4` as you specified in your question description.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have `else` in the list comprehension, `if` has to be at the end:

```
end_of_quarter_dates = [i for i in range(0, 252) if i % 63 == 0]
```

Then it will work fine.